# Passar dados contidos em Arraylist a atributos de um objeto

Tags: java, arraylist

Através do Scanner, leio um arquivo .htm e passo os dados nele contido para um ArrayList de String. Preciso atribuir esses dados do ArrayList a objetos "jogo". A classe Jogo já existe, com todos os atributos, getters e setters..

A lista está assim:

```
1 (primeiro atributo do primeiro objeto jogo)
11/03/1996
04
05
30
33
41
52
0,00
0
0,00
17
39.158,92
2016
330,21
1.714.650,23
0,00
0,00
2 (primeiro atributo do segundo objeto jogo)
18/03/1996
...
```

Esses dados já estão na ordem em que serão atribuídos, portanto, do 1º dado (índice 0 do ArrayList) ao 18º dado (índice 17 do ArrayList) é um só jogo. Do 19º ao 36º outro jogo...

Minha dúvida é simples: Qual a melhor forma de atribuir esses dados contidos no ArrayList a atributos de objetos da Classe Jogo?

Edit:

Consegui da seguinte forma:

```
private static void setJogos(List<String> listaSorteios) {

    int linha = 0;
    jogo = new Jogo();
    listaJogos.add(jogo);

    for (int u = 0; u < listaSorteios.size(); u++) {

        if (linha > 17) {
            linha = 0;
            jogo = new Jogo();
            listaJogos.add(jogo);
        }

        switch (linha) {
            case 0:
                jogo.setConcurso(Integer.parseInt(listaSorteios.get(u)));
                break;
            case 1:
                jogo.setDataSorteio(listaSorteios.get(u));
                break;
            case 2:
                jogo.setPrimeiraDezena(Integer.parseInt(listaSorteios.get(u)));
                break;
            case 3:
                jogo.setSegundaDezena(Integer.parseInt(listaSorteios.get(u)));
                break;
            case 4:
                jogo.setTerceiraDezena(Integer.parseInt(listaSorteios.get(u)));
                break;
            case 5:
                jogo.setQuartaDezena(Integer.parseInt(listaSorteios.get(u)));
                break;
            case 6:
                jogo.setQuintaDezena(Integer.parseInt(listaSorteios.get(u)));
                break;
            case 7:
                jogo.setSextaDezena(Integer.parseInt(listaSorteios.get(u)));
                break;
            case 8:
                break;
            case 9:
                jogo.setNumGanhadoresSena(Integer.parseInt(listaSorteios.get(u)));
                break;
            case 10:
                jogo.setRateioSena((listaSorteios.get(u)));
                break;
            case 11:
                jogo.setNumGanhadoresQuina(Integer.parseInt(listaSorteios.get(u)));
                break;
            case 12:
                jogo.setRateioQuina((listaSorteios.get(u)));
                break;
            case 13:
                jogo.setNumGanhadoresQuadra(Integer.parseInt(listaSorteios.get(u)));
                break;
            case 14:
                jogo.setRateioQuadra((listaSorteios.get(u)));
                break;
            case 15:
                jogo.setEstimativaPremio((listaSorteios.get(u)));
                break;
            case 16:
                break;
            case 17:
                break;                
        }
        linha++;
    }
}
```

Alguém sugere uma forma melhor?

Comment: gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void setJogos(List listaSorteios) {
```

`Jogo jogo;

    int contador = 0;
    for (int u = 0; u < (listaSorteios.size()/18); u++) {

        contador = contador+18;

        jogo = new jogo();

        jogo.setConcurso(Integer.parseInt(listaSorteios.get(contador-18)));
        jogo.setDataSorteio(listaSorteios.get(contador-16));
        jogo.setPrimeiraDezena(Integer.parseInt(listaSorteios.get(contador-15)));
        .......

        jogo.setPrimeiraDezena(Integer.parseInt(listaSorteios.get(contador-1)));

        listadJogos.add(jogo);
        jogo = null;

}`

Comment: Não deixei claro, esta lista tem 33.354 mil itens e são acrescidos 2 itens a cada semana. Se trata dos jogos da Mega-Sena.. Sua solução seria inviável neste caso. Agradeço a atenção!

Comment: Não vejo uma forma que não seja necessário percorrer toda lista, ao meu ver, o que se pode fazer é apenas dar mais desempenho no momento da busca desses dados. No caso aconselho a trabalhar com listas do tipo `Set` que possuem maior desempenho em relação a `List`.  Aconselho também a salvar a última posição do array, assim não precisará percorrer todo o array novamente quando for adicionar **os dois itens** por semana.